# Why did mathematical notation stay so hard to read?

Tags: soft-question, notation

One of the first things you learn in a programming 101 course is to write readable code, and to name your variables properly. This notion has seemingly never translated into mathematics. Everywhere you look, there are one letter constants, variables and functions, and an abundance of hard to remember symbols for operators, crammed together into tight, linearly laid out expressions. Characters are often borrowed from Greek, being short of Latin ones.

As soon as you get into college-level mathematics, any non-trivial mathematical expression starts to look like signal noise that programmers would instantly [ridicule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language) if it were a programming language.

Was there ever a movement to make mathematics more readable? Is being so succinct really worth it? Does it get better with enough experience? Would using memorable names for mathematical symbols and operators have any downside aside from length? Would a neatly indented, airier layout/syntax for expressions?

I'm not trying to stir up an argument, I'm genuinely curious, having been frustrated by this for a long time, and I'd be keen to hear what actual mathematicians think about this.

Comment: Specific examples might help your question.

Comment: Typically motivating this meta-post: [Primarily opinion-based questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4235/primarily-opinion-based-questions-answers)

Comment: Often in math variables don't actually have any practical meaning. I don't think it will help to state the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula as $\operatorname{LogOfProdOfExps}(\operatorname{FirstLieAlgElem}, \operatorname{SecondLieAlgElem} ) = \operatorname{FirstLieAlgElem} + \operatorname{SecondLieAlgElem}.+ \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Commutator} (\operatorname{FirstLieAlgElem}, \operatorname{SecondLieAlgElem} ) + \dots$ or a less intentionally-unnecessarily-wordy example along the same lines.

Comment: What @WillSawin said. Keep in mind that mathematics is often done on paper, where there is no tab-completion.

Comment: Was there ever a movement to make mathematics more readable?  My understanding is that that's at least part of what motivated Iverson's work, and … well, not everyone agrees that readability is what resulted.

Comment: Strongly related are [Why are symbols not written in words?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3277281/13130) and [Why do mathematicians use single-letter variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24241/13130) Somewhat related are [Does notation ever become “easier”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2022771/13130) and [How to avoid getting “lost in notation”](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2441940/13130)

Comment: I'd be sympathetic to this question if it were phrased more neutrally. If you're not trying to stir up an argument, then the words "crammed", "ridicule" and "really" are tendentious. Similarly, if you're asking a question of mathematicians, it would help to say that symbols are hard to remember *for you*, and that the expressions look like symbol noise *to you*.

Comment: The elementary answers available to some of your questions indicate that this post was not thought through very carefully. "Was there every a movement to make mathematics more readable?" Yes, it's the movement called "refereeing"; every referee insists on improved readability. "Does it ever get better with enough experience?" Yes, every paper a mathematician writes is improved by their continued experience with reading other papers and writing their previous papers.

Comment: I think mathematical formulas are much easier (for humans) to grasp and read than programming code. Indeed, mathematical formulas are written for humans, whereas programming code is written for computers.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: programming code has to read by computers, but that does not preclude it being written for humans, for many modern languages the latter is [the primary goal](https://learn.co/lessons/matz-readme) of the design

Comment: It is a question of habit. As a mathematician, I find computer programmers notations awkward and hard to read and memorize.

Comment: @J.J.Green : Following your link, I have found this sample of Ruby code, supposedly written for humans: "a = "\nThis is a double-quoted string\n"
a = %Q{\nThis is a double-quoted string\n}
a = %{\nThis is a double-quoted string\n}
a = %/\nThis is a double-quoted string\n/
a = <<-BLOCK

This is a double-quoted string
BLOCK"
I will probably have a headache if I try to read 50 lines of such code. Also, I see many people asking questions online such as "Is Ruby dead?"

Comment: Have you ever tried to read mathematics from the middle ages? No one letter constants and variables, all ASCII symbols. But ...

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Nice example.  Suppose you want a quote in a string, like `this is "a string"`.  You can do that in C with `"this is \"a string\""`, not nice.  The `%Q` construct allows you to write `%Q[this is "a string"]`, your string has square brackets in it?  `%Q(this [is] a "string")`,  and so on.  Why go to this effort? Because code is read more than written, and by humans.

Comment: @YCor I do see how the post can be perceived as primarily opinion based, however I don't think that the "rant" in this case invalidates the question.

Comment: @LSpice nice example, thank you!

Comment: @MattF. I understand your point, however I feel that removing all even somewhat sentimentally charged words would make any discussion much less enjoyable, while keeping them doesn't preclude the rigor with which we evaluate each other's opinions. ;) I also think that the context I gave ("being frustrated", "what actual mathematicians think") makes it obvious that this post reflects my problems specifically.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I am a software engineer by trade. I can confidently say that modern programming languages are primarily created for humans, so much so that we are willing to make trade-offs in performance to accommodate this. I personally agree that Ruby can be unreadable in the wrong hands, but the sentiment of the language's author was the point here, which is to make it more pleasant to write and read.

Comment: @WillSawin good point!

Comment: @AndrewPeterPrifer : I certainly understand the desire to make programming code as readable for humans as possible. However, the inherent limitation here is that computers, too, have to be able to understand the code. So far, any computer software seems to be very fussy about things like a missing parenthesis or a semicolon. This limitation may be overcome by AI in the future. However, given Ruby suggested as the best example of a human-oriented computer language, we seem to be very very far from that goal yet. In mathematics, fortunately we are already there. :-)

Comment: @IosifPinelis for the sake of not giving you the wrong impression about programming languages, I'd just like to say that Ruby is definitely not the best example of a human-oriented language, even if the purpose was explicitly there, and is in fact one of the languages that is often derided for being "write-only". If you want to see a modern language, take a look at Swift or Kotlin. I'm of the opinion that a well-defined syntax actually benefits humans too, I'm sure an omitted parenthesis would leave you confused too. I think we can agree there is always room for improvement in notation. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematics uses very few variable names in any proof compared to the number of variable names occuring in typical programming languages. Variable names survive only for short passages, except for a small (less than a dozen) *global* variables. The names are subject to a host of conventions (for example, $\varepsilon$ is a *small number*, $N$ is a *large number*) which are not found in programming languages. More distinct symbols are available, as we are not constrained to use ASCII. Try to rewrite a serious piece of mathematics in the style of a programming language, and you will quickly see that it is unreadable.

Comment: We are not constrained to use ASCII, but, as Halmos pointed out (not in these terms), we don't take nearly enough advantage of the full spread afforded to us by Unicode—a lot of Greek, a bit of Hebrew, and the most horrible abuse of diacritics ….

Comment: Programming languages have plenty of conventions for variable names, e.g. http://web.mst.edu/~cpp/common/hungarian.html and https://wiki.eclipse.org/Recommenders/CodingConventions#Specific_Naming_Conventions

Comment: Is it really the case that the typical computer program needs more variables than the typical mathematical text?

Comment: Maths symbols (and vocabulary) are a compromise between rigor and readability, and generally it works from the concept of relevant non-trivial example (ie. easy to generalize), the latter is what unfortunately many people forget : without relevant examples most theorems/proofs are just abstract nonsense.